# Swift NSURLSession with NSURLSessionDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, nsurlsession

I am new to Swift and iOS, want to write some basic Swift code to create a NSURLSession with defining delegate.

I've the below

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://url.com")

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration:config, delegate: XXX, delegateQueue:nil)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler:myTaskCompletionHandler)
    task.resume()
}

func myTaskCompletionHandler(data:NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, error:NSError!) {        
    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

How do I replace the XXX above with a delegate method/object name and what will be the method signature.

I was able to accomplish this for dataTaskWithURL completionHandler delegate but I am having a hard time getting this working for the session level delegate.

I know there are objective-c samples, but I couldn't translate the objective-c syntax to working swift code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this GitHub repository, a complete end to end implementation.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Alamofire.swift